# PrimeNG style classes don't work when using components, only work when using directives

Tags: css, angular, primeng, angular12

I'm developing a web app using `Angular 12` and `PrimeNG 13`.
However, I'm faced with a weird issue. Consider the two simple buttons defined below:

```
<p-button label="Delete" icon="pi pi-trash" class="mr-1 p-button-danger"></p-button>
<button pButton label="Delete" icon="pi pi-trash" class="mr-1 p-button-danger"></button>
```

According to PrimeNG documentation, these two should behave the same way. However, this is not the case for me, here's how those two buttons render in my app:

[image]

Basically, when using the component directly (the first one in the code sample above) most style classes seem to not work. For example, in the sample above the `p-button-danger` class does not apply the appropriate red background. Same goes with the other style classes I've tested. If instead I use the `pButton` directive (second one in the sample) everything works as intended.

I've used PrimeNG in the past and I'm pretty sure I didn't have this problem before... any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because they both do not work exactly the same.
For the `p-button` directive, you must use the `styleClass` attribute, because it's not directly applied to the element :

```html
<p-button styleClass="p-button-sm p-button-raised mr-2" label="Something" icon="pi pi-upload">
</p-button>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it! I must've been using it in my previous projects and didn't rememebr